# my python script prints the same value more times

Tags: python, text

**hi guys i made a script for a game in python (the game is written in python too) that logs all users name that joins in game and saves them in a text file so:**

```
 def onPlayerJoin(self, player):
    'Called for new players joined'
    nick= player.getName(full=True).encode('utf-8')
    #append
    f = open(r"ALLIDS.txt", "a+")
    f.seek(0)
    data = f.read(100)
    if len(data) > 0 :
        f.write("\n")
    f.write(str(nick)+": ")
```

IT DOESN'T MAKE ANY BUGz AND IT WORKS WELL

OUTPUT OF TEXT FILE

```
Linux31748: 
JunkieSam: 
Linux31748: 
JunkieSam: 
StratexFsk: 
Linux31748: 
StratexFsk: 
Linux31748: 
DrugrichSam: 
SapoBully: 
Stop Using /GP: 
JunkieSam:
```

**it prints the same player name more times so i want to fix that but i don't know how**

> thanks in advance for the replies , love this community every day more.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: @TheLazyScripter its disturbing to see the same nickname much times but i fixed this stuff thanks to Lei Yang

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if player already written(also I simplified some of the syntax):

```
def log_player(player_nick, file=r"ALLIDS.txt"):
    with open(file, "a+") as f:
        f.seek(0)
        # TODO: improve algorithm, this is just showing the concept
        if player_nick in f.read(): 
            return
        f.write(f'{player_nick}\n')


def onPlayerJoin(self, player):
    'Called for new players joined'
    nick = player.getName(full=True).encode('utf-8')
    log_player(nick)
```

Can you have a try?

Answer (score 0):

Before you write a player's name, you should check whether the name is existed.

Check code:

```py
def is_name_existed(name):
    with open(r"test.txt", "r") as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        for line in lines:
            if line == "{}: \n".format(name) or line == "{}: ".format(name):
                return True
    return False
```